# What do symmetries of equations in presentation of a group tell us about the group?

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose we have some group $G$, presented with some set of equations. If we are to collect up some subset of  equations which define the presentation as $P$ (don't need all), then does swap of variables which preserve the actual group implied by the presentation   $P$, tell us anything interesting about the group $G$?

Example:

Let's say we have for instance a group generated by $\{a,b,c\}$ with the relations $abc=b$, $abc =a$. Then in the for this group, we see that if we swap $a \leftrightarrow b$ , then the actual relation is same.  The swap of variables give same equation hence the group implied is same.  By implied group I mean, the group one gets when one applies the equations on the free group generated by the set.

By the way, It could also have been the case that we get different poly equation which imply the group as same.

Comment: Why do you insist on misusing "polynomial" to refer to relations in a group presentation? They are not polynomials, they are "words".

Comment: So, it came to my mind since they look like polynomials and it ogt stuck. I have edited since @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Its hard for me to understand what you are asking. Could you rewrite this to be more grammatical? And it would help a lot to give an example of what you are talking about

Comment: What do you mean it is not grammatical? I think it makes sense when I read it. Anyways, here you go: So, let's say we have for instance a group generated by {a,b,c} with the relations abc=b , abc =a . Then in the for this group, we see that if we swap a<-> b , then the actual relation is same. So, in general, if such a phenomena happens, what does it mean for the actual group @IsAdisplayName

Comment: Cyclically presented groups might interest you. It's a very active field of research.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I have a hard time parsing "does swap of variables which preserve the actual group implied by the presentation P". Anyways, its worth adding the example you give (and more detail) to the question. Maybe include what kinds of properties you are interested in.

Comment: In the case, the swap of variables give same equation hence the group implied is same. It could also be the case that we get different poly equation which imply the group as same. @IsAdisplayName

Comment: Please put information and/or clarification i. the post, not buried in comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "imply a group"? This is what I don't understand. @TrystwithFreedom

Comment: You should be using MathJax by now . . .

Comment: The operation $a\mapsto b, b\mapsto a$ preserves (as you noticed) the group relations, so it descends to an endomorphism of the group. In this case, and arguably in the case of any "symmetry", the operation is reversible. Therefore symmetries of a presentation of a group $G$ at least tell you which groups are subgroups of $\text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: The relations you give immediately yield $a=b$, and then $abc=b$ give $c=a^{-1}$. So your group is the infinite cyclic group. That said, your claim that swapping $a$ and $b$ result in the same relations is false. You go from $abc=a$ and $abc=b$ to $bac=b$ and $bac=a$. Though they imply the same thing (the group is infinite cyclic) they are *not* the same relation.

Comment: The relations correspond to generators of a normal subgroup of the corresponding free group. If $F$ is a free group on $X$, then every permutation of $X$ induces an automorphism of $F$, but this automorphism need not preserve normal subgroups. If the set of generators is invariant under some of these automorphisms, you are saying the group has a corresponding automorphism swapping generators.